# Java rmi server with multiple client - Only accept one client call at the time

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

I'm developing a standard java RMI server with multiple clients. These clients have a menu where they can call the server to do various of things for them.

One method involves a queue, where they can send a job to the queue and wait for it to get handled. The RMI server dispose threads for all the clients automatic, but when it comes to this method and queue, how can I hold this request back, so for example:

client 1 call first, and then client 2 calls just after (here client 1 should receive the message first from the server and client 2 should wait the time it takes for the server to process client 1 request)

Is it to make some kind of singleton only for this task?
What can I do to tackle this problem.

Comment: Seems to me like a monitor issue. Have you tried using synchronized methods?

Comment: @JacekCz It isn't all that complicated, and it isn't necessarily an enterprise application. If you don't know anything about RMI you're not really adding anything useful here.

Comment: agree that "not complicated", but common words, used in branch, are helfull. I'm not religious "pattern" follower, but can help in communication

Comment: @JacekCz They only help if they're relevant, and they aren't here. All it takes to solve this problem is a single Java keyword, and you wouldn't find it by all the 'enterprise patten'-based searches in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Make the remote method concerned `synchronized`.

No queue required.